# Data format convertion from string to date error in data refinery, watson studio

Tags: ibm-watson, dataformat

When i convert string to date in data refinery for say 24/12/1948 to dmy, it will be converted to 24-12-2048. The year is wrong. How to correct this? Thank you.

Comment: Please post everything you tried, everything you attempted to do to fix it, and info about what documentation you looked at etc

Comment: What i did was simply 'convert data type' from string to date for the birthdate column using IBM data refinery.  the original data which is presented as 24/12/48 (Str) was converted to 24-12-2048 (date). The format i had selected for conversion is 'dmy'. Thanks.